# How do I convert a Tensorflow model to .mlmodel?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, coreml

I want to convert a Tensorflow model with the following structure to a .mlmodel file for use in an iOS app:

```
cub_image_experiment/
   logdir/
       val_summaries/
       test_summaries/
       finetune/
          val_summaries/
   cmds.txt
   config_train.yaml
   config_test.yaml
```

I'm following this tutorial: https://github.com/visipedia/tf_classification/wiki/CUB-200-Image-Classification
However, I'm having trouble understanding the structure of the project. Which files are important and how do I convert all the separate config files and everything into a single .mlmodel file so that I can use in my application?

I've looked online and all I could find was how to convert .caffemodel to .mlmodel or .pb file to .mlmodel. These are all single files, however my project has multiple files. I found a tutorial on how to convert a tf model into a single .pb file, however, that model's structure was different and it did not contain any yaml files. My project is not focused on creating a model at the moment, but merely integrating a model into an iOS app. I found this model interesting for an app idea and wanted to know if it can be integrated. If there are any tutorials out there that might help me in this sort of problem please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of that stuff is used by the Core ML model. The yaml files etc are used only to train the TF model.

All you need to provide is a frozen graph (a .pb file) and then convert it to an mlmodel using tfcoreml.

It looks like your project doesn't have a frozen graph but checkpoints. There is a TF utility that you can use to convert the checkpoint to a frozen graph, see https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py

Comment: Are the checkpoints all the summaries? I'm sorry if this feels like a stupid question, I have no idea what's going on here. Are there any tutorials that explains all this?

Comment: From the README for that repo it looks like the "finetune" folder will have the checkpoint files. The problem with tutorials etc is that different TF projects will do things in a different way. The https://github.com/tf-coreml/tf-coreml repo has documentation and examples on how to convert TF models to Core ML. (There is also my book Core ML Survival Guide, see the link in my profile.) But none of these will explain exactly what is needed for your particular model, as each model is different and TF has multiple ways to do the same thing.